# How to personalize Auto API Controllers endpoints in APB Framework

Tags: c#, abp

I'm learning APB framework. ABP can automagically configure the application services as API Controllers by convention. The documentation says it is possible to fully customize it.

In the [example](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/AspNetCore/Auto-API-Controllers) they provide, I would like to change an action name of one of the following endpoints:

`/api/app/book` to `/api/app/books`.

[image]

But unfortunately I cannot find how to do it.

I tried to change the `ActionName` of the corresponding service method:

```cs
public class BookAppService :
        CrudAppService<Book, BookDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,
            CreateUpdateBookDto, CreateUpdateBookDto>,
        IBookAppService
    {
        public BookAppService(IRepository<Book, Guid> repository)
            : base(repository)
        {

        }

        [ActionName("books"), HttpGet]
        public override Task<PagedResultDto<BookDto>> GetListAsync(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
        {
            return base.GetListAsync(input);
        }
    }
```

But the resulting endpoint is not what I want:

[image: Resulting endpoint]

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

in abp.io (ABP VNext) , you can diable or configure `ConventionalControllers` in `HttpModules` config file of your Project .
Edit this Method :

```
private void ConfigureConventionalControllers()
        {
            Configure<AbpAspNetCoreMvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConventionalControllers.Create(typeof(SystemApplicationModule).Assembly);
            });
        }
```